# Chinese and Japanese most important high school textbooks

Tags: precalculus

I would like to know the best high school math books from Japan and China. Can you suggest some books or free resources? I would like to compare the different approach betweeen China and Japan and Europe. Thanks.

Comment: Are you interested in a specific level? Primary, lower secondary, upper secondary? Do you read Chinese or Japanese, or are you looking for translations?

Comment: Thanks for your answer @JustinHancock. I'm interest in lower and upper secondary. I am looking for translation since i don't speak japanese and chinese

Answer (score 4):

The only full-length English translations of Chinese or Japanese secondary math textbooks that I'm aware of are [the ones listed here](https://ucsmp.uchicago.edu/resources/translations/), which were produced by the University of Chicago School Mathematics Project. There are seven books in total, covering grades 7 to 11. The original textbooks were from the 1980s.

There isn't a very large market for translated school textbooks to begin with, and especially not at the secondary level. If you're interested in comparing different approaches, I would instead look for math education research articles on international textbook comparison. For example, [this article by Wang and Xu](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11858-018-0977-6) presents results from a study commissioned by the Chinese Ministry of Education during their revision of the national high school mathematics standards. The authors compare the content of high school textbooks in China, France, Germany, Japan, Russia, the United Kingdom, and the United States.

There are many more articles on international textbook comparison—it's a popular area of research. [Here's a Google Scholar search to help you find more articles.](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?&q=secondary%20mathematics%20textbook%20comparison)